# Jquery autocomplete is failing when object.keys is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data like below .I'm trying to get all Switches(keys) and display auto complete option suggestion with these switches.But failing by saying file not found error in JQUERY. Is there something that im missing here?

My logic is :

```
    //data
    var tags2 = {"Switch1":"ip1","Switch2":"ip2","Switch3":"ip3","Switch4":"ip4","Switch5":"ip5"};

    //getting keys
    var s1=Object.keys(tags2) ;

    var s2=JSON.stringify(s1);
    alert(s2);

    $('.autoc').on("keydown", function(){
          $(this).autocomplete({
           minLength: 1,
           source: s2
            });
    });
```

URL:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_553/6x24mybw/50/)

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine as far as I can tell. A file not found error suggests the javascript file can't be found by your DOM file.

Check you have the right path in your html script tags. Or try putting this script directly in your html file (inside `<script>`) and see if it works then.